# ItemGetter - Ordenar lista de dicionários - Python

Tags: python

Vamos supor que eu tenha a seguinte lista de dicionários:

```
lista = [{"nome": "Maria", "idade": 15},
          {"nome": "João", "idade": 26}]
```

E estou usando a seguinte função pra ordenar:

```
ordenar =  sorted(lista, key=itemgetter("idade"))
```

Porém só quero que me apresente os nomes pela ordem decrescente de idade, do maior para o menor, ou seja: `["João", "Maria"]` sem que me apresente o dicionário inteiro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o parâmetro `reverse` do [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) para fazer o sort e criar uma nova lista com o resultado, ficando +/- como mostrado no exemplo abaixo:

```
lista = [{"nome": "Maria", "idade": 15},
    {"nome": "João", "idade": 26}]

# Faz o sort
ordenar =  sorted(lista, key=lambda row:row['idade'] , reverse=1 )

# Criar uma array só com o nome
ordenar = [ row['nome'] for row in ordenar ]

print(ordenar)
```

<sup>[Exemplo online](https://repl.it/repls/CautiousInsignificantLists)</sup>

---

Para fazer o sort por mais de uma coluna, no parâmetro `key` você vai precisa retornar uma [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) como mostrador no exemplo abaixo.

```
sorted(lista, key=lambda row:( row['idade'], row['nome'] ) , reverse=1 )
#                            ^                           
#                          tuple com o valor de idade e nome
```

Comment: Obrigada! funcionou direitinho, só mais uma dúvida, caso eu queria ordenar por uma mas mostrar ambas colunas, como ficaria?

Comment: Adicionei um outro exemplo mostrando como pode ser feito o sort com mais de uma coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é tirar as informações relevantes dos dicionários e depois ordenar.

```
#formo uma nova lista só com as informações que interessam e sem o dicionário
lista_sem_dicionario =  [(dic['idade'],dic['nome']) for dic in lista]
#ordeno do maior para o menor e pego só o nome
[l[1] for l in sorted(lista_sem_dicionario, reverse=True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ficou um pouco maior do que imaginei, mas acho que dessa forma vc ganha mais autonomia pra ordenar e pegar resultados diversos.

```
lista = [
{"nome": "Maria", "idade": 15},
 {"nome": "João", "idade": 26}]

def organiza(lista, ordenador, *retorno):
    aux = []


    for dct in lista:
        l = []
        for i in retorno:
            l.append(dct[i])
        plv = "{} : {}".format(dct[ordenador],','.join(l))
        aux.append(plv)
    aux.sort(reverse=True)
    resultado = []
    for i in aux:
        resultado.append(i.split(':')[1].strip().split(','))
    return resultado

print(organiza(lista,'idade','nome'))
```

Na função acima. Vc entra com a lista no primeiro argumento o item pelo qual vc quer ordenar e por último os itens que vc quer de retorno.

Dessa forma vc pode colocar mais itens no dicionário sem ter que mexer novamente na função.